# Development of asymmetric encryption algorithm?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am planning to develop (make some minor changes) to asymmetric encryption (i.e. RSA). Any suggestions please?

Comment: Never roll you own Crypto. [Don't be a Dave!](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/1132/5400) ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oRvP7.jpg)

Comment: The fact that you're asking for suggestions means that you shouldn't do it.

Comment: With all three of your questions in mind, I have to ask - Are you organizing a particularly bad CTF competition? Because that's pretty much the only good use for bad crypto that I can think of. All other uses of bad crypto will only end up in you being the laughing stock.

Comment: TildalWave, If you have a technical answer just write down, but I do not think that you have any one......

Comment: What is your goal in changing RSA? Change for change's sake is dumb. Change with a specific goal can be a necessary evil, but one has to be really careful. But for us to help you with that, you need to describe your goal. I'm developing an RSA signature variant, but only because I couldn't find an existing scheme which does what I want.

Comment: @user27889 It's not possible to make good suggestions for changes if we don't know your goal. Many cryptography standards are one of the few schemes that work among similar looking but weak schemes. Most naive changes will only be fit for CTFs, not for security.

Comment: @ CodesInChaos Please check the detailed answer for my question in this link.... http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38427/protection-of-online-image-file-ancient-manuscript

Answer (score 11):

Well, one suggestion: don't do it. Or, at least, do it for fun, not for actually protecting anything.

It is exceedingly difficult to design a secure cryptographic algorithm. After decades of research, professional cryptographers have found only one method, which is "a lot of scrutiny": an algorithm will be deemed "secure" only after it has been inspected by dozens of other cryptographers for many years, and none of them found anything bad to say about the algorithm. Every detail counts in such inspection, down to the last bit.

Therefore, regardless of what are the changes you envision and how "minor" they look to you, you will not be able to know if the result is secure or not (and, incidentally, the overwhelming majority of "modified algorithms" are *not* secure).

Even implementing an algorithm, without deviating from the published standards, is difficult, because implementations will most often leak information about the secret values they process (see [timing attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack)). A basic RSA implementation is little more than some code which handles big integers (and there are [good libraries](http://gmplib.org/) for that), but protection against side-channel leakages is a full-blown active research area, which cannot be summarized in a single Security.SE answer.